# Accessing the original value of the unicode string when subclassing unicode

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, subclass, python-unicode

Try to get a class which would work like so:

```
>>> original = u"ABCD-123-foo"
>>> suffix = SuffixComparingUnicodeString("foo")
>>> suffix == original    # if original ends with suffix, True
True
```

I know it's silly. Please bear with me.

Anyway, I can't figure out how to get the actual, er, *string* (not `str`, mind) from within the `unicode` object. I can do it like this just fine:

```
>>> class SuffixComparingUnicodeString(unicode):
...     def __init__(self, x):
...          super(SuffixComparingUnicodeString, self).__init__(x)
...          self._myval = x
...     def __eq__(self, other):
...          return isinstance(other, unicode) and other.endswith(self._myval)
...
>>> SuffixComparingUnicodeString("foo") == u"barfoo"
True
```

How can I do it without storing that value myself? What does `unicode` call its underlying character sequence?

Comment: I'm sorry, what's your question? How to get the non-unicode version of the string you used to initialize it?

Comment: `unicode` calls its "underlying string" `self`. It's like trying to get the `3` out of a `3` object. If you want an instance of `unicode`, you can use `unicode(self)`.

Comment: @agf I'm asking: if you have `myuni = unicode("foo")`, what is the member `unicode` uses to talk about `u"foo"` inside the `myuni` instance? It's hard for me to articulate it, but, I feel like it's pretty clear what I'm asking otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you a subclassing `unicode`, instances of `SufficComparingUnicodeString` can usually be used just like any other Unicode string.  So you can just use `other.endswith(self)` in your `__eq__()` implementation:

```
class SuffixComparingUnicodeString(unicode):
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return isinstance(other, unicode) and other.endswith(self)
```